# How to use proper injection of variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to use proper injection of product id in javascript.

```
  $(".vote_count").wrap("<a id='id' href='countvotes/{product_id}'</a>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is: "I have a `product_id` variable and want to put it where I have `{product_id}` in this code," there are three answers: *(The answers are essentially the same if you're talking about `id` instead, just make the appropriate changes.)*

1. String concatenation:

   ```
   $(".vote_count").wrap("<a id='id' href='countvotes/" + product_id + "'></a>");
   ```
2. ES2015 (aka ES6) template strings:

   ```
   $(".vote_count").wrap(`<a id='id' href='countvotes/${product_id}'></a>`);
   ```
3. Any of several templating engines.

Usually, best to combine those with `encodeURIComponent`, because you're outputting a URI, and so if `product_id` has things in it (like `/`) that have special meaning in URIs, you need to escape them. So:

```
$(".vote_count").wrap("<a id='id' href='countvotes/" + encodeURIComponent(product_id) + "'></a>");
```

or

```
$(".vote_count").wrap(`<a id='id' href='countvotes/${encodeURIComponent(product_id)}'></a>`);
```

Taking that a bit further: Since you're outputting the content of an HTML attribute, you *also* have to ensure that what you're outputting is valid HTML text. There's no built-in for that, but it's a trivial function to write:

```
var escapes = {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '"': '&quot;'
};
function escapeHTML(str) {
    return str.replace(/[&<"]/g, function(ch) {
        return escapes[ch];
    };
}
```

*(There's no need to escape `>`, but you can if you like.)*

Using that, I always enclose my attributes in double quotes (since those are what I'm escaping).

So:

```
$(".vote_count").wrap('<a id="id" href="countvotes/' + escapeHTML(encodeURIComponent(product_id)) + '"></a>");
```

and

```
$(".vote_count").wrap(`<a id="id" href="countvotes/${escapeHTML(encodeURIComponent(product_id))}"></a>`);
```

---

Side note: You were missing the closing `>` on the `<a` tag. That's fixed in the above.

Comment: @DanielA.White: Done. And HTML handling, too. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For *ES5*, like this

```
$(".vote_count").wrap('<a id="id" href="countvotes/' + encodeURIComponent(product_id) + '"></a>');
```

For *ES6* you can use [`string templates`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

```
$(".vote_count").wrap(`<a id="id" href="countvotes/${encodeURIComponent(product_id)}"></a>`);
```

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for the help bro!